# Is there a difference between i. and absorb in stata?

Tags: regression, stata

I would like to know if there is a difference between i. and absorb(). I think both options allow to control by time or individual dummies, but I have seen the use of both options at the same times in some sites and papers replicates. This is more a conceptual question. Something like this:

```
areg x y  i.year, absorb(z) cluster(id) 

areg x y i.year i.z, cluster (id)
```

year in this case are the time dummies and z are the individual(id) characteristic dummies. Are both commands equivalent?

Comment: Absolutely. First off, using factor variable notation (which emphatically is not an option in Stata's sense) is general across many Stata commands while as far as I know the `absorb()` option is specific to `areg` as an official command and community-contributed commands influenced by it. Second, and otherwise in commands where both are allowed, there are differences in what is calculated and what is reported. The manual entry for `areg` is more informative on this than the help file.

Comment: areg is intended for a setting where the number of categories is fixed (like states in the US, or occupations) as you add more data. The best way to handle user FEs is to use xtreg or user-written reghdfe rather than i. dummies. These can accommodate the case where you get more parameters as you add more data, both computationally and also the standard errors.

Comment: Ok, it its more clear to me, thanks!

Comment: @NickCox, your comment should actually be an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comment by [Nick Cox](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1820446/nick-cox) suggests, the main difference is that i.z will report the estimated coefficients of the indicators for each level of z, while absorb(z) will calculate them but not report them.
[The manual for areg](https://www.stata.com/manuals13/rareg.pdf) directly states "problems with more variables than the largest possible value of matsize" as one reason to use areg over reg.

Consider also looking at [reghdfe](http://scorreia.com/help/reghdfe.html), a command created precisely to overcome issues with multiple fixed effects (in your case, year and z)